# Range Query Question: Removing Items from a List

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

My task is to input a given list of size `N`, then process `N` queries that remove an item from the list and then print it to the screen.

The input

```
5
2 6 1 4 2
3 1 3 1 1
```

would represent having a list `{2 6 1 4 2}`, then outputting and removing the third, then first, then third, then first, then first elements of the list, in that order. The correct output would be `1 2 2 6 4`.

My first idea to solve this problem runs in `O(N^2)` time; simply use a dynamic array to achieve `O(1)` random access and worst-case `O(N)` removal. However, as `N` can be up to `10^5` in this problem, this solution is *way* too slow. I think that the problem is probably looking for an `O(NlogN)` solution.

In the end, I read the hints for this problem, and they said that this problem has an `O(NlogN)` solution involving Range Queries. I've learned about Segment and Fenwick Trees, as well as the sparse table algorithm, but I still don't know how to solve this problem. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's solvable with a segment tree. Notice that you want to avoid to remove elements from your array because it costs O(n). We rather want to have another array where we mark all the elements removed as 0 and all that are not yet removed as 1.

Comment: Now consider what you could do with a segment tree over this new array...
(basically for the query "remove ith number" you want to find the ith "1" in the new array, which is possible with a sum segment tree...) Do you need further hints?

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for your excellent comment and for answering so quickly (you should make the comment an answer!).